# Measuring Execution Times

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I was wondering which `time.time()` of `from datetime import timedelta` was the quickest and best way to find how long a programme had been running for example.

```
import time
start = time.time()

#do stuff

print(start - time.time())
```

or (although longer)

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start_time = datetime.now()

def millis():
   dt = datetime.now() - start_time
   ms = (dt.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + dt.seconds) * 1000 + dt.microseconds / 1000.0
   return ms
def tickscheck(start):
    x = 0
    count = 0
    while millis() - start < 1000:
        x = 4+5
        #counting up
        count = count + 1
        print("It Took " + str(count) + " Counts\nOver " + str(millis()- start) + "ticks")

running = True
while(running == True):
    tickscheck(millis())
```

Comment: What is your goal here — just to benchmark the Python interpreter on your machine?

Comment: @200_success basically yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For benchmarking process times in Python, you should probably use the `timeit` module.

It is designed specifically for this purpose and you can keep your code clean by running it from the command-line.

This example is from the docs:

```
$ python -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
```

For example, if the process you want to benchmark is a function `foo`

```
$ python -m 'timeit --setup 'from my_module import foo' 'foo()'
```

The snippet given with the `--setup` flag sets up the environment in which you can run your test.

Check out the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html) for more information

Comment: thnx ill look into it

Answer (score 9):

In Python 3.3 and later you can use one of

> [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)
>   Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a
>   performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available
>   resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed
>   during sleep and is system-wide. The reference point of the returned
>   value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of
>   consecutive calls is valid.
>
> [`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time)
>  Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the
>   sum of the system and user CPU time of the current process. It does
>   not include time elapsed during sleep. It is process-wide by
>   definition. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so
>   that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is
>   valid.

Older Python versions offer [`timeit.default_timer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer), which is now an alias of `time.perf_counter()`.

The [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module offers tools to get more reliable timings by running the code multiple times.