# "FIZZ BANG BUZZ!" 3,7,11 efficiency

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, fizzbuzz

I wrote a fizz buzz variation method in Python which prints "fizz", "bang", and "buzz" for 3, 7, and 11 respectively.

```
def FizzBang():
    string = ''
    for n in range(1,101):
        msg = ""
        if not n % 3:
            msg += "Fizz"
        if not n % 7:
            msg += "Bang"
        if not n % 11:
            msg += "Buzz"
        print msg or str(n)
```

What can I do to increase the speed of this program? I know the modulus is quite expensive. Also maybe concatenating strings might not be needed as well.

Comment: You could write it in a native language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, addition is faster than modulo.  This implementation runs about 33% faster than the original when counting up to 100.  However, I expect that it wouldn't scale as well to larger limits due to its O(*n*) memory usage.

```
def fizz_bang(limit=100):
    limit += 1
    strings = [''] * limit

    fbb = ((3, 'Fizz'), (7, 'Bang'), (11, 'Buzz'))
    for stride, noise in fbb:
        for n in range(0, limit, stride):
            strings[n] += noise
    for n in range(1, limit):
        print strings[n] or n
```

Also, according to PEP 8 conventions, `FizzBang` should be named `fizz_bang` instead.

Comment: You could address the memory usage by putting the two `for` loops within a larger loop, that is, compute 1000 or 10000 or some other reasonably large number of output values, print them, and then reuse the memory for the next batch of values.  There would be some computational overhead to set values for the inner loops on each iteration of the outermost loop, including three uses of the modulo operation. (On the other hand, in practical terms we would probably all lose interest in the output before memory use became a problem.)

Comment: @DavidK Actually, the array size can be bounded by the LCM of 3, 7, 11, which is 231. After that it cycles.

Comment: Good point!  Yes, of course, so there is still no need to do a modulus.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the modulo operator is as expensive as you think it is, and even if it would be there's no way you can avoid it.

However, instead of doing string concatenation you can write to `sys.stdout` directly. This however, requires a temporary variable to know if any previous number has been written already.

Also, your `string` variable has a bad name, and seems to be unused.

If the code in your question is Python2, [use `xrange` instead of `range`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange) (if it is Python3, no harm done as the `range` method in Python3 *is* Python2's `xrange`)

Python 3 code:

```
def FizzBang():
    for n in range(1,101):
        written = 0;
        if not n % 3:
            sys.stdout.write("Fizz")
            written = 1
        if not n % 7:
            sys.stdout.write("Bang")
            written = 1
        if not n % 11:
            sys.stdout.write("Buzz")
            written = 1
        if not written:
            print(str(n))
        else:
            print()
```

Comment: I've measured this to be about 3% slower than the original (basically a non-issue), and certainly uglier.

Comment: @200_success That explains the downvote. (Well deserved). In that case I think the best suggestion is: Stick to the old code.

Comment: @200_success this answer is slower? Hmm does this answer use less memory? (string concatenations)

Comment: @200_success would using `print "Fuzz",` make things faster? Notice the comma.

Comment: Indeed, `print "Fizz",` makes it about 10% faster than `sys.stdout.write("Fizz")`, probably because `print` is built-in rather than a function call in Python 2.  As for any difference in memory usage, I challenge you to find _any_ measurable difference.

Comment: I have to admit I did not know about the `print "Fizz",` approach. :)

Comment: @200_success i'm not sure how to measure this =[ but from reading posts here and there, I've learned that strings are immutable and concatenating them is expensive and a new string object is created for each concatenation. I am not sure how to measure this so all the backup I have is from previous posts that I've read =/

Comment: @Liondancer We had a recent Python question [about measuring time](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48416/measuring-execution-times)

Comment: To measure performance, use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). As for memory, your solution and Simon's solution both use O(1) memory, and the amounts are tiny.